# grid-auto-flow:column with 1fr as width

Tags: css, css-grid

## Is it possible to use `1fr` as the column-width with `grid-auto-flow: column`?

### `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr)`

So that the width of each column would be the same and defined by the widest column, but I can only achieve it by defining the number of columns:

[image: Example for grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr)]

### `grid-auto-flow: column`

I'm in need of `grid-auto-flow: column` because the amount of columns is variable, but I want to have them in the same width, without defining it in px:

[image: Example for grid-auto-flow: column]

Comment: The clue is in the name. It's about flow not width. What you want is not possible with Css-grid

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `grid-auto-columns: 1fr`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.grid>div {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Grid has the `auto-fill` and `auto-fit` keywords, that can do this for you (if I'm fully understanding what you want, at least):

#### HTML

```
<div class="grid">
  <div>col1</div>
  <div>col2</div>
  <div>col3</div>
  <div>col4</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.grid > div {
  background: red;
}
```

Results in https://codepen.io/isaactfa/pen/zYWWKQK.

I'll let Sara Soueidan explain the difference between `auto-fill` and `auto-fit`: https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/.